# Gradle Build Broken

Tags: android, build, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I upgraded Android Studio (to 1.0.2) and it seems the LibraryVariant is missing the packageLibrary property now. When I try

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.packageLibrary.exclude( 'libs/motiongestures-api.jar' )
    variant.packageLibrary.exclude( 'libs/headtracking-api.jar' )
    variant.packageLibrary.exclude( 'libs/home-api.jar' )
}
```

I get

```
Error:(43, 0) Could not find property 'packageLibrary' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.LibraryVariantImpl_Decorated@744bd358.
```

I'm using

```
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

but I also tried other build tool versions with no success. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Rolled back to com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2 and it is working again on the command line. (I had to revert back to gradle 1.10)

Comment: I have the same issue, I can't revert back to 0.12.2 did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.packageLibrary.exclude('.......')
    }
}
```